# Why to use this javascript arrow function or what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I stumbled upon this relatively simple arrow function:

```js
var x = ([a, b] = [1, 2], {x: c} = {x: a + b}) => a + b + c;
console.log(x());
```

I know what it does in general. But why does it this thing so complicated? I mean, the same thing can be done much easier and has (*imo*) a better readability too:

```js
var x = ([a, b] = [1, 2], c = a + b) => a + b + c;
console.log(x());
```

So could someone tell me the difference of this two notations or show me a better usecase for the first one?

Comment: In this case, not much. In general, this syntax allows a lot more. [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thank you for the link. At first I didn't got the reference to the examples. But now, after the answers, I got the it. @JacqueGoupil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd argument of your 2nd is example is a simple es6 default initialization, while the 2nd argument of your 1st example is again a simple es6 default initialization with destructuring. 
But, I assume you already know that.

Your other part of the question was,  *show me a better usecase for the first one?*

Destructuring is mainly useful when you want to access a key from a huge javascipt object;

Something like this:

```
 aHugeJavascriptObject = {
   key1:'value1',
   .
   .
   .
   key999:'value999'
 }
```

Now, one way to access the object's key `key999` is `aHugeJavascriptObject.key999`, instead you probably want to do

```
 const { key999 } = aHugeJavascriptObject
```

I also assume that you already also know that.
But, I am afraid that is what that is there to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like your intention. So if I understand your idea correct, you mean something like this: `var obj = {key: 3}; var x = ([a, b] = [1, 2], {key: c} = obj) => a + b + c;`. Well, at least that is a nice inline translation of names, but could even be done with `c = obj.key`. This would become nicer on more parameters in the function! So, not bad. Or did I miss your point?

Comment: Yes, exactly, You can either use destructuring or `c = obj.key`, which ever suits you. But, if you have a huge object, writing `obj.yourKeyName` everytime to access the key, the `obj` part becomes redundant. Instead if you already know what key to access you can do `{yourKeyName, someOtherKey} = obj. 
But it doesn't really matter, both does the same job, it is just less code more work.
I hope you get the point.`

Comment: Well, that's a pretty nice explanation of a usecase. Thank you very much, you put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The first notation takes an object with a property `x` as the second argument. It is destructured and `x` is extracted as `c`. If it is not defined, a default object with a property `x` is used instead:

```
console.log(x([1, 2], {x: 5}));
```

Whereas the second one takes a simple argument primitive argument (probably a Number in this case):

```
console.log(x([1, 2], 5));
```

The only difference thus is the second argument that is fed into the function.

Comment: Yes, that is the explanation of *what* is does and *how* it works. That's the part I'm knowing too. ;) But that is not the answer for *why*.

Comment: `So could someone tell me the difference of this two notations` I literally did ;) As to why you would use it: If you pass an object as an argument with plenty of other properties, it would just pick out the one you need. Sorry, I've used this quite a bit so it seemed obvious to me and I misunderstood your question. nitte93user3232918 explained it quite nicely.

Comment: I not wanted to debase your answer. ;) For me it was not fully clear what you wanted to tell me with your answer. I thank you for your effort!